# System.OutOfMemoryException when batching data to client using Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am currently using Microsoft Sync Framework to Sync Data from a mssql database to a sqlite database hosted on Windows Phone 8. I am using the SyncToolkit.

I am using SetDownloadBatchSize to restrict the data sent over the wire to prevent the System.OutOfMemoryException, but I am still receiving it almost like the framework isn't disposing the old batch sets.

It works(syncs) successfully when I have say 4,000 rows of data, when I increase this data to 30,000 rows it fires this exception.

Any assistance would be helpful before I rip this framework open and try hack it out.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: is the out of memory coming from the sync codes itself? or are you really running out of memory deserializing the sync data, loading Sqlite and running your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the framework that I manually corrected as it was open source.

Now everything is syncing fine.

Answer (score 0):

How do you implement sync service ? If you implement as wcf service configure the message size both wcf service and and client config files

COnfiugre the binding. for example wcf service web config file

```
<binding name="largeMessageHttpBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Comment: Configure message size on web config file on wcf service and client config file.  i have added sample code for wcf service web config file to the answer